# Can my query including encrypted data be optimized

Tags: c#, postgresql, encryption, sha256

Company for which I work has new requirement related to GDPR. Their demand is to encrypt all user data in a database using AES256 encryption. Second rule is that the database is not allowed to store secret key to decrypt data. It is stored in c# app and all encryptions/decryptions are done there.

Because of that now we suffer big performance issues. We're forced to load all data from the database in order to sort and paginate it in memory, instead of using SQL ORDER BY and LIMIT commands.

My question is if you have any ideas to improve the process? Maybe there is a hash function allowing elements to stay in proper alphabetical order? Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the price you have to pay for security. If the encrypted data were ordered like the unencrypted data, it would be possible to guess the content by comparing to known values.

The best option is usually to be selective about which columns to encrypt and which to leave unencrypted: there is no need for an index on the credit card number.

If you have to sort using an encrypted value, you are pretty much lost. Your only chance is to limit the result set.

Try to negotiate a compromise, like storing the first two characters of a name in clear text. Make your client understand that you cannot get both speed and security; there will have to be compromises in both directions.